# Missing compiler_cxx fix for UnixCCompiler

Tags: python, gcc, scipy, clang

I'm trying to use a python package on my Mac OS X ([pynbody](https://github.com/pynbody)) and getting the following error:

```
>>> pynbody.analysis.halo.center(h1,mode='hyb')
TipsySnap: loading data from main file
creating /var/folders/f6/whg92p6x23q4drf5s563prw40000gn/T/scipy-carljoseph-YozSSU/python27_intermediate/compiler_10a3badd5737329477237726cc2e9ec1
#### ['/usr/bin/clang', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fno-common', '-dynamic', '-pipe', '-Os', '-fwrapv', '-DNDEBUG', '-g', '-fwrapv', '-O3', '-Wall', '-Wstrict-prototypes'] #######
Missing compiler_cxx fix for UnixCCompiler
```

Am using python 2.7.6 on OS X Mavericks and have `clang` installed as part of Xcode 5.1.1:

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

`gcc --version` gives me the following:

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any ideas on what I can do to correct this `Missing compiler_cxx` issue?